# Why Chrome is sometimes creating a new virtual machine VM and sometimes not?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, webassembly, mediapipe

Look at my example at codepen :

https://codepen.io/jimver04/pen/gORdBwp

When I see in the console

```
put_char    @   selfie_segmentation_…_simd_wasm_bin.js:9
```

everything works well.

When I see

```
put_char    @VM152  selfie_segmentation_…_simd_wasm_bin.js:9
```

or whatever @VM+number everything is stack.

How can I force to run selfie_segmentation_…_simd_wasm_bin.js without VM number ?

See also my issue posted in Mediapipe : https://github.com/google/mediapipe/issues/2590

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because linked code tries to access users camera.

Comment: So what ??? the Selfie-Segmentation application of mediapipe is a selfie camera application, how it can be used without a camera ???

Comment: Some of us don't have cameras, some of us don't want to be seen. If you can, reproduce this problem with a sample image or video. If not, it might be better to explain why. Otherwise, this can be seen as a malicious attempt to steal user pictures.